# How to use requests to replace selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I used Selenium to get the result using the following code.

```
import requests
import selenium
import time


driver.get(r'http://www.example.com')
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
a.send_keys(r'C:\mypic.jpg')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//result[@output='data']").click()
c =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//category[@id='front']").text
```

How to use `requests` to get the result?

Thank you.

Comment: Relevant part of  HTML is needed to answer your question. To be honest I don't understand your question, what result are you looking for, are there any problems with your code, is there an exception thrown?

Comment: There is no problem with the above code.

Comment: I just want to use the `requests` package to do the same job because selenium is slow.

Comment: Using time.sleep makes your code slow and brittle, using ExplictWait instead of time.sleep will speed up your code a lot. See: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: For example, requests.post() may be able to simplify the steps and get the results faster.

Comment: Did you check how the POST looks like in Network tab of dev console? Did you try to make it with `requests`?

Comment: I tried to make it using `requests.post` but I cannot get the results.